# Opencart - Hide A Category from Sitemap & Search Engine

Tags: php, opencart

How can I hide a category from my Opencart Sitemap? [`route=information/sitemap`] and also search engine crawlers?

I have a category (`store.com/private`) which I would not like in search results or in the website sitemap. Is there an extension or code that I could vQmod to achieve this result for categories?

As there is no folders called /private, I do not believe I can put /private simply in the robots.txt file to stop it indexing the category. If I am misinformed, please correct me! Also, as opencart has two url's for the same category, one being the route to category id, so does this cause further problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put all the possible URLs for that category into the `robots.txt` file. If the `private` category does not have children (sub-categories) and thinking of it's ID as 1, this could be the content:

```
Disallow: /private
Disallow: /private/
Disallow: /index.php?route=product/category&path=1
```

For the sitemap the easiest solution with least effort is to add a check into the template directly. First make sure the `category_id` is visible to the template changing the `catalog/controller/information/sitemap.tpl` default code:

```
$this->data['categories'][] = array(
    'name'     => $category_1['name'],
    'children' => $level_2_data,
    'href'     => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category_1['category_id'])
);
```

into this one:

```
$this->data['categories'][] = array(
    'category_id' => $category_1['category_id'],
    'name'     => $category_1['name'],
    'children' => $level_2_data,
    'href'     => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category_1['category_id'])
);
```

and then in the respective template file change

```
<?php foreach ($categories as $category_1) { ?>
<li><a href="<?php echo $category_1['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category_1['name']; ?></a>
<!-- ... -->
</li>
<?php } ?>
```

into this:

```
<?php foreach ($categories as $category_1) { ?>
<?php if ($category_1['category_id'] != 1) { ?>
<li><a href="<?php echo $category_1['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category_1['name']; ?></a>
<!-- ... -->
</li>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

(still expecting the ID of the `private` category to be `1` - adjust this value if it differs). This solution for sitemap should hide the `private` category as well as it's possible children. It is quite OK if you need to hide only one category but if you'd like to hide more of them in the future I recommend doing the cleaner way described below.

The cleaner but more effort-wise solution would be to add a new setting in the administration and a new DB column for category allowing you to set whether the category should be listed in the sitemap or not and then the category and it's children and other data should be retrieved for sitemap **only** in the case that category is enabled for sitemap. Such setting could look exactly like the `Status` setting (e.g. a select with *Enabled* and *Disabled* options and `1` and `0` values stored in DB). The category model `catalog/model/catalog/category.php` should be adjusted whith the `getCategories($orded_id)` method being copied into `getCategoriesForSitemap($order_id)` while adding a condition to the query checking that category is enabled for sitemap. This method should then be called in the sitemap controller.

Comment: Sorry for not replying sooner, i've had a nightmare and my house flooded! Laptop gone! Recovered it all and back online now, currently reading through your reply

Comment: Your first solution to the SE crawlers, it was my understanding that the crawlers look at only the robots.txt file in the domain root. Does this apply to subdomains? I have googled this and cannot find a solid answer. My web store is in the folder `/shop/` and I have other content in the root of the public folder. I therefore have a subdomain for this folder: `http://shop.domain.com`.

Comment: As for the solution of adding the code to the controller file and tpl files directly, I agree! This is the only fix I can think of to be honest and your answer supports it. I will vQmod these core file changes! Adds a spec of load time but it is a sacrifice I will have to pay! :) Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. To the `robots.txt` for subdomain, simply place it into `/shop/` dir and if the subdomain is pointed to this `/shop/` dir it should work correctly. Oh and I hope you already recovered also your flooded house! Wish you all the best!

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I did not know this, I'll put this in place tonight. And yes, everything should be fine. Only two rooms flooded, but my laptop was on the floor. Nice!